# Show only To-dos with today's due-date in Android app

Tags: java, android, date, listview, calendar

For my app I need a function that only shows the to-dos which due date is today. I am new to Android Studio and Java, so unfortunately I do not know how to write this code.

**This is my code so far:**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getIdemid()) {
        case R.id.menu_dailyToDo:
            showDailyTodo();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
       }
    }
}

public void showDailyTodo() {
    if(tvDueDate == //today) {
        // code that listview items with duedate today are shown.
    }
}
```

All I could find so far could not help me.

### Edit

In the picture you can see my listview.

[image]

The date is a TextView with ID tvDueDate.

Comment: Remove `Android-Studio` tag, this causes a confusion that you are talking about `ToDo`s inbuilt in `Android-Studio`. Add `android` tag instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get current time upto milliseconds as long datatype.

OR

You can use `Date d = new Date();` to get the date as a Date object and convert it to String in desirable format like

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(d);
```

It depends on datatype and format in which you have stored dates in tvDueDate.

Then you can set Todos Items into a ListView adapter as shown in this post
[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

**EDIT**

you can get your due date in a String using

```
String dueDate = tvDueDate.getText().toString();
```

Then do

```
public void showDailyTodo() {
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(d);
if(dueDate.equals(formattedDate)) {
    // code that listview items with duedate today are shown.
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Your `ToDo` class should have a member variable of type `LocalDate`. And optionally a getter method.

```
public class ToDo {
    public LocalDate whenDue ;

}
```

## Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Compare

Compare using methods on `LocalDate`: `isEqual`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `equals`.

Loop your to-do items, comparing the date to the target, today's date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;  // Or `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
List< ToDo > todayToDos = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( ToDo todo : todos ) {
    if( todo.whenDue.isEqual( today ) ) {
        todayToDos.add( todo ) ;
    }
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateUtils library in android to check if the due date is today or not.

Here is a link to the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#isToday(long)

For getting listview items, just loop through the items and check if their due date is today or not and filter out the items. You can pass those items to the adapter of the listview. For comparison of individual item, a rough implementation would be:

```
long timeInMillis = dueDate.getTime();
if (dateUtils.isToday(timeInMillis)){
    //this is today's item, so add this to a list which is sent to the listview
}
```

Comment: this sounds exactly what i need, but I am not able to write the correct code :(

Comment: Which specific part are you having trouble with? If you have a class for todoItem which consists of due date and an arraylist<todoItem>, it should be easy to filter out your required result.

Comment: the big problem is, i do not know how to compare the due date from the todo with the current date. I added a screenshot of my listview with four todos.

Comment: If your dueDate is a date object, I have added some code for comparison above which should work.